# Trouble Altering Table SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

Hey guys just wondering what i'm doing wrong in this script.

```
ALTER TABLE SSV_TOURS (
ADD CRUISE_ID# CHAR(5),
ADD CONSTRAINT TOURS_CRUISEID#_FK FOREIGN KEY (CRUISE_ID#) REFERENCES SSV_CRUISES(CRUISE_ID#)
);
```

When i do the ADD commands individually the table alters, so I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: error message.................?

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, `alter table` only allows one modification at a time.  You can see this in the syntax diagram in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF01001):  There are no back arrows.

So:

```
ALTER TABLE SSV_TOURS ADD CRUISE_ID# CHAR(5);

ALTER TABLE SSV_TOURS ADD CONSTRAINT TOURS_CRUISEID#_FK FOREIGN KEY (CRUISE_ID#) REFERENCES SSV_CRUISES(CRUISE_ID#);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't mix column_clause and constraint_clause in one alter table sentence. However in your case you either need to split your alter table to two (one with add column and other with add constraint) or slightly rewrite your statement as

```
ALTER TABLE SSV_TOURS (
ADD CRUISE_ID# CHAR(5) 
    CONSTRAINT TOURS_CRUISEID#_FK FOREIGN KEY (CRUISE_ID#) 
    REFERENCES SSV_CRUISES(CRUISE_ID#)
);
```